# Screen stretching on Mint Cinnamon after hard reboot

Tags: linux-mint, desktop, cinnamon, display

I've been running 64-bit Linux Mint Cinnamon for a couple of years now on my current hardware. I upgraded to Qiana a month ago and hadn't had any problems with it.

This morning my machine locked up when I accidentally loaded a huge file via a python script that was apparently too big to fit in memory. I couldn't even get to a tty and had to hard reboot. The machine came back up, but now my desktop and all applications are stretched horizontally maybe 50 pixels, which looks ghastly and will seriously interfere with web development work.

The login screen looks fine. Adjusting the horizontal size and position of my ViewSonic monitor display via the monitor itself doesn't affect the application stretching. I have an Intel 4 Series integrated graphics controller with no proprietary drivers. I haven't manually installed or updated any new packages for at least a week, although I do run `unattended-upgrades` for security repos.

```
$ xdpyinfo | grep dimensions
  dimensions:    1600x1200 pixels (423x318 millimeters)
```

See [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xqxeudvbcdgon7s/Xorg.0.log) for `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Display Settings**

Did you check under `System-Settings -> Displays` (the names might be slightly different)?  The screen resolution may have changed to one that isn't the same aspect ratio as your monitor.  This setting is per user, which is why your login screen looks fine.

**Test User**

Create a test user (as root):-

```
#useradd -m testuser
#passwd testuser
```

Log out and log in as this new user and check the screen resolution.  If it's good, then the issue is a configuration within your user account.

Comment: `Displays` detects my display correctly, and gives the resolution as `1600 x 1200` which is what it has always been.

Switching to `1680 x 1050` stretches the display vertically instead, but by a smaller amount and is an improvement.

Comment: With the display back at the original (ugly) resolution, run `xdpyinfo | grep dimensions` and post the results.  Also, post the output of `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`.  It might be better to use a service such as pastebin for the log as it's rather long and post the link here instead.

Comment: I've appended the requested information to my question.

Comment: The logs look fine. They show the resolution changing.  Did you log out/in a few times?  I've added a (rather desperate) suggestion to the answer.  Hopefully the testuser will be OK and we can track down the offending config.

Comment: Rebooting with the new `1680 x 1050` resolution seems to have fixed it, for both users, which is a relief. Thank you for all your help.